# Writing to row headers in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Can you tell me how can i write row numbers into row headers in datagridview in c#, like in excel.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this;

```
void Gridview1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()).ToString();
  }
```

**EDIT**: First code for `Gridview`, for `DataGridView`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace DataGridView2
{

    class DataGridView2 : DataGridView
    {

        protected override void OnRowPostPaint(DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnRowPostPaint(e);

            // get the row number in leading zero format, 
            //  where the width of the number = the width of the maximum number
            int RowNumWidth = this.RowCount.ToString().Length;
            StringBuilder RowNumber = new StringBuilder(RowNumWidth);
            RowNumber.Append(e.RowIndex + 1);
            while (RowNumber.Length < RowNumWidth)
                RowNumber.Insert(0, "0");

            // get the size of the row number string
            SizeF Sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(RowNumber.ToString(), this.Font);

            // adjust the width of the column that contains the row header cells 
            if (this.RowHeadersWidth < (int)(Sz.Width + 20)) 
                this.RowHeadersWidth = (int)(Sz.Width + 20);

            // draw the row number
            e.Graphics.DrawString(
                RowNumber.ToString(), 
                this.Font, 
                SystemBrushes.ControlText, 
                e.RowBounds.Location.X + 15, 
                e.RowBounds.Location.Y + ((e.RowBounds.Height - Sz.Height) / 2));
        } 
    }
}
```